# TypeError:Dataset is null

Tags: csv, d3.js, xampp

I am creating d3 graphs from csv file.
I am sure that my code is syntactically alright.
I got my code running previously and everything was working fine.But suddenly the browser console shown error  TypeError:Dataset is null 
for the same code.I also tried installing xampp server but dont know how it will work for my jsp files.Can anybody help me.

Comment: Without any code or other indication of what you're doing we can't possibly help you.

Comment: here is the link to my code    https://db.tt/wfaEsqFZ

Comment: Also here is my csv file link sir
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzt8qameo2hgydu/example.csv

Comment: I guess that the name of your dataset changed and you didn't change it in the code. Did you verify paths etc and that everything is deployed correctly?

Comment: yes i had changed the name of the file accordingly.I had checked all the paths too.The main thing is whether is it possible  that the same code which was running in good condition will not work in future...and that too with the same browser...?

Comment: So what did you change between the code working and not working?

Comment: Nothing;I had changed.I had saved the previouy running code for which I had given the link and then changed the code a little bit more animation(tooltip) was added but it too worked and suddenly stopped working.
Then I tried to run the previous code ;it also stopped working...how come this possible now.
I searched for the reason then I came to know that it is something related with the browser

 https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/d3-js/mynA6oNnUC4

But nothing worked!!